# CoreData: error: (migration) migration failed with error (null)

Tags: ios, core-data, migration, mapping

I'm trying to get my head around core data migration.

Basically, we've had 15 data models and until now we were fully happy with the inferMapping  and autoMigration options :

```
NSDictionary *lcOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
```

Now I've got a field to rename, a relationship to delete and a new one to create. I went for the mapping model thing as I thought it would work ok but it's not.

Basically, the migration goes ok until the end when it says :

```
[Migration doing OK apparently]
2013-10-23 18:19:25.561 MyApp[80546:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, ....
2013-10-23 18:19:25.562 MyApp[80546:c07] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0004s
2013-10-23 18:19:25.562 MyApp[80546:c07] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0008s for 2 rows.
2013-10-23 18:19:25.562 MyApp[80546:1b03] CoreData: annotation: Disconnecting from sqlite database.
2013-10-23 18:19:25.564 MyApp[80546:1303] CoreData: annotation: Disconnecting from sqlite database.
2013-10-23 18:19:25.564 MyApp[80546:c07] CoreData: annotation: (migration) leaving incompletely migrated store on disk after automatic migration failure. (file://localhost/Users/vdesaintpern/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/1B73B767-2BFC-4716-B93B-E9CFA29952A8/Library/Application%20Support/.MyDatabase.sqlite.migrationdestination_41b5a6b5c6e848c462a8480cd24caef3)
2013-10-23 18:19:25.564 MyApp[80546:c07] CoreData: error: (migration) migration failed with error (null)
2013-10-23 18:19:25.564 MyApp[80546:c07] Unresolved error (null), (null)
```

->Crash

My database is in Library/Application Support and it seems to be fully readable / writable.

The "leftover" (.MyDatabase.sqlite.migrationdestination_41b5a6b5c6e848c462a8480cd24caef3) from Core Data is fully readable and seems to contains all the data I need properly migrated.

I've tried it many times, recreated the mapping model, doing through the whole process again and again. No luck.

Well, being honest it worked last week and it's not working any more (I checked out the exact revision I committed when I saw it working). Didn't change XCode or anything in my system.

I found a guy with the same problem on a mac but unfortunately the workaround is not applicable on iOS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is it now? Automatic or non-automatic migration? Did you try to use `@NO` for the NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption when migrating with a mapping model?

Comment: Yes I did. It didn't change anything...

Comment: Did you set both options to @NO?

Comment: Same problem. Still no luck.

Comment: Strange, we also had issues after 15 versions. Although I could not understand what the problem was, providing a mapping model helped.